# Bubble sort not correctly sorting list

Tags: python

I've written the following bubble sort, why won't it output the correct results?

```
number = [8,6,4,5,7]
while x == True:
    for i in range(0,len(number)-1):
       if number[i]>number[i+1]:
     x == True 
     number[i],number[i+1]=number[i+1],number[i]
  x = False   
print(number)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation on your code; it is impossible to tell how the (wrongly-used) `x = False` should be indented, so I cannot fix this myself.

Comment: It would help if you provided the current results also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're setting `x = False` at the end of your `while` loop, so the loop only ever run once, set it on the first line of your loop.
2. You use `x == True` instead of `x = True` so your loop will only run once as `x` remains `False`.
3. You don't set `x = True` before your loop starts, so it won't even enter the loop.
4. Your indentation is incorrect (this is probably from the copying your code here as otherwise it wouldn't run at all).

Changing all this will result in your code working:

```
>>> x = True
>>> number = [8,6,4,5,7]
>>> while x == True:
...     x = False
...     for i in range(0,len(number)-1):
...        if number[i]>number[i+1]:
...            x = True
...            number[i],number[i+1]=number[i+1],number[i]
...
>>> print(number)
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```